# Is there an adjectival form for "good etiquette"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example, when we say someone has ***good courtesy***, we can say they are ***courteous***.

Is there an analogous word for having ***good etiquette***?

Comment: I would say *well mannered*, but you rarely need the adjective; in this sentence, I would say *Bob has good manners*.

Comment: If you take _etiquette_ to mean _the rules of polite society_ then _polite_ would do nicely.

Comment: Is it not possible to act *politely* but with poor *etiquette* and vice-versa? I am trying to think of an example. But I believe 'etiquette' implies something more than politeness. One refers, for example, to *professional etiquette*, which is what it is considered proper and improper to do in a professional relationship. This doesn't seem to me to be directly equivalent to being *polite*.

Comment: Incidentally, I think your title should refer to *adjectival form*.

Comment: @WS2: Then again, there is *polite society*, which is not necessarily polite...

Comment: @WS2 I'm sure it is/was given that _polite_ is much older than _etiquette_ but _etiquette_ (in the form I assumed the question was intending) are now the rules of politeness.

Comment: *Etiquette*, from its French origins, means *sticking to convention*. Therefore, the adjective form is *conventional*.

Comment: @Frank But the two words are used in quite different contexts. *Etiquette* is more formally contextualised. 'Politeness' involves saying please and thankyou, or giving up your seat on a train to an elderly or infirm person. 'Etiquette' is a formal expectation, concerned with such things as who one invites to a wedding, the conversations between opposing lawyers etc.

Comment: @WS2 I think politeness is more than just 'please, thank you etc.'. I would be impolite to urinate in a lady's handbag and then say 'Please, excuse me I have a weak bladder'. You may have politely apologised but your actions were not at all polite. To me etiquette includes courtesy and manners, not just which spoon to use when eating. (I will admit that I have never seen a rule in any etiquette guide forbidding urinating in a lady's handbag)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it already contains its own answer, being therefore based on the false premise that *courteous* and *well-mannered* refer to different things. Since a person who shows good manners is *courteous*, no further word is needed nor applies.

Comment: @WS2 Your point about *professional etiquette*  is a good one. The OED calls this “The unwritten code of honour by which members of certain professions (*esp.* the medical and legal) are prohibited from doing certain things deemed likely to injure the interests of their brethren, or to lower the dignity of the profession.”

Comment: @congusbongus Just what do thing *etiquette* means?

Comment: I think there are nuances between words. Courtesy and being well-mannered is slightly different than being correct in etiquette but there are similar senses of course and the meaning can depend on the context. I think it is a good question.

Comment: @ermanen: I would say *etiquette* is something of an "abstract noun", on a par with, say, *performance*. First, both can be positively or negatively adjusted with an adjective such as *good, poor*. Second, both are normally assumed to be *positive* unless explicitly modified by a negative adjective *("You have no etiquette!", "This is a performance car")*. Third, both can be used as adjectives themselves (a type of car as just given, or *an etiquette handbook*). Fourth - it simply doesn't *mean* anything to ask for an "adjectival form" unless you specifically mean "of **good** etiquette".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's a good explanation. Shall we modify the title of the question to save the day?

Comment: @ermanen: I think we have to be a bit careful here (I take it you mean "Shall we include the word **good** in the title?"). It's really up to the OP to frame his question (it's not like we haven't offered plenty of advice in these comments! :). But I've already sided with tchrist and closevoted. Although *courtesy* and *etiquette* pretty much share semantic space, that's no reason why they should be syntactically comparable. If *"Alice acts with aplomb"*, does that mean we should expect there to be an adjectival form of *aplomb?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for your suggestions, but please **be bold** and edit if you think it improves the question. Rather than a chorus of advice, I'm sensing more of a cacophany!

Comment: @ congusbongus: I see your point! Unfortunately, there *is* no derived form of *etiquette* that could adjectivally identify a character trait - those upvoting *etiquettal* are just being misled by the form of the "error/neologism" (which has only 24 instances in the whole of Google Books, and all of them within the past few decades), and the "correct" adjectival derivative **etiquettical** (which has several hundred GB results) isn't used to describe *people*. So we're just left with the close synonym *courteous*, which some argue isn't a close *enough* synonym.

Comment: OMG.  Everyone wait until you see my next answer.

Comment: @Joe: I'm not wild about the question in the first place. But I *am* a bit perturbed by the number of upvotes for *etiquettal*, which I don't even consider to be a valid word (it's just a bungled version of *etiquettical*). If that doesn't get knocked off the top spot in a day or two, I might just make a *cause celebre* of it, by posting a bounty. (Though that would piss me off even worse if loads more people came in and voted for the duff answer, so it's potentially a high-risk strategy! :)

Comment: For me the really important thing I've realised from this whole enterprise, is that "good etiquette" is a meaningless phrase; etiquette is a word like procedures or law, it's not a word like behaviour or elocution. I will never again use "good etiquette" to refer to a person who is following good etiquette -- it's obvious once you realise it.

Comment: How about _etiquetical_? It makes a nice adverb: _Etiquetically speaking, I'd have to say that was a mistake._

Comment: Might mannerly do?

Answer (score 7):

According to OED, the only "valid" adjectival derivative of *etiquette* is...

> ***etiquettical*** *- relating to etiquette; observing or prescribed by etiquette*

...for which the most recent of their six citations is...

> 2008 National Post (Canada) (Nexis) 10 May (Weekend section) 2
>   *"None of this would have happened had he done the etiquettical thing"*

There are [several hundred instances of "etiquettical"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22etiquettical%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books. Leafing through them I can't see any where the term is directly applied to a *person*, but the *observing ... etiquette* definition above certainly implies that in principle it *could* be thus used.

As to the alternative derivation ***etiquettal*** (which doesn't seem to feature in any authoritative dictionaries), I would simply note that there are [only 15 legible instances in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22etiquettal%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), all from the past few decades. In light of that I'd say it's just an erroneous form.

---

In practice it seems people don't actually apply *etiquettical* (or its bastard offspring *etiquettal*) to *people*, even if in principle they could). Probably the most common adjective (putting aside nitpicking over fine semantic distinctions) is OP's own ***courteous***, but I think it's worth noting that ***manners*** shares with *etiquette* the fact that although it *can* be qualified both positively and negatively *(good manners, bad manners)*, the default interpretation of the word is positive.

So although there are adjectival forms such as ***ill-mannered*** and ***well-mannered***, we don't actually *need* to qualify the term to force the positive interpretation. Here's an instance in a letter from Byron (pub. 1844)...

> *I desire nothing better than to dine in company with such a **mannered man** every day in the week :
>
>   but of " his character" I know nothing personally; I can only speak to his **manners**, and these have my warmest approbation.*

Comment: *Manners* can still mean 'good manners', but surely you would have to concede that Byron's usage of *mannered* is archaic: when did you ever hear it spoken, or see it in anything written in the past century? Today, the principal connotation of 'mannered' approximates to 'stilted, artificial' (see, for instance, the [Macmillan definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mannered): *behaving, speaking, or writing in a way that is extremely formal and not natural*.

Answer (score 6):

Though not used very often, in fact, very rarely, there does exist an adjective for "etiquette", as described [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/etiquettal) and [here](http://www.definitions.net/definition/etiquettal)

> etiquettal English[edit] Adjective[edit]
>
> (rare) Of, or pertaining to, etiquette.

However, for all practical purposes, you're better off using terms like "well-mannered".

Check out the definition of the term from the [Merriam-Webster link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-mannered)

> **well–mannered** adjective
>
> :  having or displaying good manners :  showing good taste :  properly
>   behaved :  courteous, polite, well-bred

Also, take a look at usage of this term in some sentences, [here](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/well-mannered), such as-

> She is a very **well-mannered** and polite young woman who engages
>   well with all and particularly contributed to great teamwork with her
>   male classmates

Comment: Though the adjective *etiquettal* exists, it certainly doesn't work in the query sentence: "Bob is etiquettal because he acts with proper etiquette" sounds ridiculous. Which goes to demonstrate that the question presented by the OP is horribly misleading, because it suggests that the word required to replace the blank is modelled on the *courteous/courtesy* pairing. Anyway -- I'm with you that **well-mannered** is probably the right solution here.

Comment: @ErikKowal I'm not familiar with the word *etiquettal*, but why doesn't it work in the query sentence?

Comment: @congusbongus - Because as Dark Knight's cited definition shows, it means 'pertaining to etiquette' (e.g. "etiquettal traditions"), rather than 'displaying good etiquette'.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work - and the reason the whole question is meaningless - is explained in my answer.

Comment: OED does not acknowledge the existence of ***etiquettal***. They have ***etiquettical***, but both the definition and all six citations strongly suggest it's only used of *behaviour or objects **relating to etiquette***, not to identify a *person* as "conforming to [good] etiquette".

Comment: @Dark - I'm afraid to say this answer is completely wrong, and I have to downvote it for that reason.  honestly, now that the error has been explained at length, surely you should just delete or edit the question?

Comment: @JoeBlow What makes you think that I suggested the use of terms like etiquettal/etiquettical? While I did point out the existence of "etiquettal", which by the way, does have a valid link and description, my original answer was "well-mannered". And next, my answer was to the original question - _"Bob is ------- because he acts with proper etiquette"_. Now that the OP has changed the question to _"Is there an analogous word for having good etiquette"_, of course I agree that the question doesn't make sense, because there's no such thing as "good etiquette", as you've also pointed out.

Comment: @JoeBlow And when you suggest that _"honestly, now that the error has been explained at length, surely you should just delete or edit the question?"_, surely you meant it for the OP?

Comment: hi @dark. quite simply, your answer does not make clear that etiquettal is not the sought answer.  So, insted of saying "However, for all practical purposes..." you should edit it to "and that's not what you are looking for. So..."

Comment: regarding the OP, the whole question should be deleted :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to suggest ***proper***. Though, it is usually used with a noun after.

> Strictly following rules or conventions, especially in social behavior; seemly: *a proper lady; a proper gentleman.*
>
> <sub>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proper</sub>

There is also a loan phrase from French, ***comme il faut***, which literally means 'as is necessary' and it can be used in the same sense of *proper*.

> Correct in behaviour or **etiquette**: *my friend is partial to cocaine—in every other way he is very proper and comme il faut*

And there is ***decorous*** which is used for proper people who behaves with decorum.

> **Social decorum** sets down appropriate social behavior and propriety, and is thus linked to notions of **etiquette** and manners.
>
> <sub>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorum</sub>
>
> ---
>
> characterized by dignified propriety in conduct, manners, appearance, character, etc.
>
> <sub>Source:http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/decorous</sub>

The book "The Facts on File Guide to Good Writing" (By Martin H. Manser) explains the difference between decorous and decent and I wanted to share because it is related:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest **polite** as it means **showing good manners toward others**, which should be the essence of good etiquette.

Comment: Btw, the comments to the question indicate a disparity between being polite and showing good etiquette. Is it a hair to split? 

Etiquette: the customary code of polite behavior in society or among members of a particular profession or group. (Google Define Etiquette).

Answer (score 2):

> ***Punctilious***: showing great attention to detail or **correct behavior**
>
> ***Civil***: obeying the norms of civilization; **polite but not friendly**
>
> ***Proprietous***: conforming to accepted standards of **behavior** or morals (see also @ermanen's "proper")
>
> ***Decorous***: marked by propriety [see above] **and good taste**, which goes above and beyond politeness (also suggested by by @ermanen)
>
> ***Nice*** [in a somewhat obsolete sense]: 
>   characterized by, showing, or requiring great accuracy, precision, skill, **tact, care, or delicacy**

Answer (score 2):

From the OP:

> Question: Is there an adjectival form for “good etiquette”?
>
> For example, when we say someone has good courtesy, we can say they
> are courteous.
>
> Is there an **analogous** word for having good etiquette?

It is clear the OP is **not** asking for synonyms of *to have good etiquette*.  Such information can easily be retrieved by a Google search[1] by selecting a noun **which does** have a corresponding adjective.

The analogy the OP refers to is the **relationship** between the noun *courtesy* and the adjective *courteous*, where they are indisputably derived from the **same root**.  Synonyms therefore are **not** analogous in **this context**.

As several users have pointed out, there is the adjective *etiquettical* which is derived from the same root as the noun *etiquette*.  But does it fit the analogy offered by the OP?  This post seems to suggest that it cannot be used to describe people.

> I can't see any where the term is directly applied to a person...In practice it seems people don't actually apply etiquettical. (FumbleFingers)

Does *etiquettical* pass the analogy of the OP?

(1a) He has good *courtesy*.  He is *courteous*.

(1b) He has good *etiquette*.  *He is *etiquettical*.

From these examples it does not.  Therefore *etiquettical* is not an analogous word (via the analogy defined by the OP).

Instead, here is an example of how *etiquettical* is used.  Note that it sounds a bit bizarre in (1c) to substitute it with adjectives like *courteous*, *well-mannered*, *polite*, etc.

> Prudential obligation may conflict with *etiquettical* obligation[2]

(1c) *Prudential obligation may conflict with *courteous*/*well-mannered*/*polite* obligation.

Since the only adjective derived from the same root as *etiquette* does not fit the analogy, it is safe to say that the answer is no.  There is not an analogous adjective for having good etiquette.

**References**

[1] http://thesaurus.com/browse/etiquette

[2] http://books.google.com/books?id=IXe0Ho-4hMcC&pg=PA212&lpg=PA212&dq=etiquettical+books&source=bl&ots=IinRCRfp0W&sig=-lr7kMp60IWhUONLG_DbnFXqcgQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZbHhU7nJA4ewyATPjYGABw&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=etiquettical%20books&f=false

Answer (score 1):

I think [formal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Formal) may fit:

> - Following or being in accord with accepted forms, conventions, or regulations:  went to a formal party.

As shown below, etiquette has little or nothing to do with being polite or well-mannered. Politeness may be the apparent result of following etiquette rules which are just a code of behaviour you have to adopt in specific contexts. Formality, meaning  *an established form, rule, or custom, especially one followed merely for the sake of procedure or decorum.* is its main characteristic.

[Etiquette](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/etiquette):

> - (Sociology) the customs or rules governing behaviour regarded as correct or acceptable in social or official life
> - (Sociology) a conventional but unwritten code of practice followed by members of any of certain professions or groups: medical etiquette.

Source:Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridge

Comment: _formal_ usually refers to the behavior, not the person.

Comment: *"As shown below, etiquette has little or nothing to do with being polite or well-mannered"*  I think that's somewhat confusing, Josh, for the following reason. As you say "medical etiquette" or "courtroom etiquette" (for example), have no connection to "politeness".  But if you ask "what is politeness?" the answer is, simply and nothing other than, "social etiquette" (in other contexts more specifically, say "table manners" is "eating etiquette").

Comment: @JoeBlow - I think politeness can be defined as  'the act of showing regard for others' while etiquette refers to a  more structured behaviour. You can be very polite irrespective of etiquette.

Comment: Name the film!  "Do you know why we have table manners? .. To make others feel comfortable."  (Beautiful isn't it.)  I understand, but the phrase *"etiquette has little or nothing to do with being polite"* is just going too far and is confusing. (It would be as if I said "diesels have utterly nothing to do with engines!". Sure, there are other engines and there are planets with no! diesel engines.) In every situation we will ever be in, the "showing regard" you mention is achieved by that situation's etiquette. For sure in extremely unknown hypothetical situations (on Mars) where....

Comment: ...there's no etiquette to follow, you have to just try your best to "be respectful"

Comment: Film: "Blast from the Past". Also, when can you separate good etiquette from being polite? "Oh, I'm not being polite. I'm just following acceptable customs!" "Well, I'm not offended by your actions, as they follow acceptable customs, but I can tell you're just following the rules of social acceptability, without regard to my feelings, so you're note really being polite..." Ack. The mind twists. The whole point of etiquette is to be socially correct. The byproduct of that is by definition being polite.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is meaningless because etiquette (in English) **is neither good nor bad**, it's a noncountable quality like, say, "weight".

Note that you can have a truck, say, of low weight or of high weight.

Quite simply, there is no adjective of such words.

(It's confusing that people are **giving you examples of adjectives of "good etiquette"** - similarly there are adjectives for "bad etiquette".)

"etiquettical" is an adjective of etiquette but not in the sense you mean. "etiquettical books", for example, would be **books related to etiquette**.

Anyway - all of this shouldn't need to be explained **at such astounding length**. Etiquette is a **noncountable quality** (such as for example "weight" or "size"); there is no adjective.

Secondly it's very confusing if you mean "good" or "bad" etiquette. Thirdly the answers here ("ways to say good etiquette" are confusing).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion; I have now edited the question to mean "good etiquette".

Comment: You can have my upvote, anyway. I can't believe so many people here are rooting for the obviously incorrect *etiquettal* (itself just a recent and erroneous form of the actual word *etiquettical*), while  downvoting this perfectly correct summary of the problems presented by the question.

Comment: I feel on this site sometimes the good-hearted desire to provide huge amounts of information (in itself, good & correct information) sometimes outweighs the precisely-answer-question concept!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific usage you're going for, '**genteel**' may suit your purpose.  It's not an exact fit, but I see better matches which have not been marked as answers, so I get the impression that you are looking for something with a better connotative fit:

> gen·teel adjective \jen-ˈtēl\ : of or relating to people who have high
>   social status
>
> : pretending or trying to have the qualities and manners of people who
>   have high social status
>
> : having a quietly appealing or polite quality
>
> **1** a :  having an aristocratic quality or flavor :  stylish
>
> b :  of or
>   relating to the gentry or upper class
>
> c :  elegant or graceful in
>   manner, appearance, or shape
>
> d :  free from vulgarity or rudeness : 
>   polite

It can also be used negatively:

> **2** a :  maintaining or striving to maintain the appearance of
>   superior or middle-class social status or respectability
>
> b (1) : 
>   marked by false delicacy, prudery, or affectation
>
> (2) : 
>   conventionally or insipidly pretty (timid and genteel artistic style)

Source: "Genteel." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 5 Aug. 2014. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genteel.

Answer (score -5):

I'm afraid I have a further point in relation to the **NEWLY EDITED VERSION OF THIS QUESTION**

The question asks for another way to say

***"good etiquette"***.

You know, I'm not really sure that "good etiquette" is a well-formed concept. In short **"good etiquette" is bad English, it's not a well-formed phrase**.

Heh!

So, ettiquette is "what you do."

So, we'd say stuffs like: "a person who always follows etiquette" or "I don't know the etiquette in this situation" or "someone who is careful to observe etiquette" or "driving etiquette in Italy is remarkably different from Germany" or "are you following etiquette?" or "what's the etiquette in this sort of meeting?" .. and so on.

I actually believe, I'm afraid to say, it is simply poor English, poorly conceived, to say "good etiquette".  What you mean is someone who follows etiquette.

{**NOTE** -

"good etiquette" would be meaningful in the following: "I"m a student of driving etiquette in various European regions. It's fascinating that for example in Provence, the driving etiquette is _ blah blah blah _, whereas in southern Italy, the driving etiquette is _ blah blah blah _.  For me, the Italian version is a good etiquette; I just don't like the French driving etiquette.  Also in my opinion, Germany driving etiquette was a good etiquette - but their driving social norms have changed lately; I do not like the current German driving etiquette."

See what I mean?}

When you say "good etiquette" in the question title, what you are trying to say is **someone who is always careful to follow etiquette**. Right?  (Obviously, meaning the etiquette in the social milieu in question - naturally etiquettes are wildly different in different eras, regions, etc.)

To explain it simply, "etiquette" is a word similar to "law" or "rulebook".

Note that it is **not** similar to say "behaviour".

Note that phrases like "he has good law" and "he has good rulebook" are not well-written.  What you mean there is "he always follows the law" or "he adheres to that rulebook".

In contrast, it's fine to say "he has good behaviour".

I'm afraid to tell you that, in short, **you cannot say "good etiquette"**.

I bet Churchill would never have written "that was good etiquette" - He'd say "that was a good demonstration of etiquette" or some such.

All the examples you google up, are poor writing.

{Footnote - since the question has utterly changed, I don't see a problem with posting two answers here.}

---

Finally, regarding what you're literally trying to get at: someone who adheres to (the prevailing) etiquette (in the milieu in question): the only phrases that truly do that are phrases like:

-- she adheres to etiquette
-- she follows etiquette
-- she's a stickler for etiquette
-- she is etiquette-abiding

There **is no** single word form.  (I'm pretty sure there's nothing for the equivalent for "law" either, other than law-abiding.)

---

One final point in your question you mention "good courtesy". There's no such thing.  it's like saying "good height".  You can have a lot of courtesy, much courtesy, little courtesy, etc.  "Tall" does not mean "good height", it means "a lot of height".  "Courteous" does not mean "good courtesy", it means "a lot of courtesy".